# C# Deserialize a Serialized JSON string

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json-deserialization

This is the JSON string which I received

```json
{
   "Date":"2021-11-16",
   "Name":"Raj",
   "BError":{
      "code":"errorcode",
      "details":"message"
   },
   "AStatus":true
}
```

I have to Deserialize the above JSON string

I have given the class details with JSON annotations below

```
public class Demo
{
    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    
    pulic string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("B-Error")]
    public BError BError { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("A-Status")]
    public bool AStatus { get; set; }
}
    
public class BError
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

the code I have written to Deserialize is

```
var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input_JSON_string).ToString();
Demo d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Demo>(responseJson);
```

this code is converting input_JSON_string into object but not all fields.
The fields "Date" and "Name" is converting but the fields "B-Error" and "A-Status" is storing values as NULL.

How to Deserialize all the fields?

Comment: You don't _need_ to define `JsonProperty` above - it's typically used when your properties names _differ_ from the `JSON` etc. - and based on the above, they don't...

Comment: @EdSF you say that.. but then people would forget to put a camelCasing converter in so all the *serialized* json ends up PascalCase; euww. One bonus of JsonProperty on everything is that it's one less thing to remember for the serialize part (and it's easy for json-to-csharp type converters to turn out)

Comment: As stated below, JSON and code mismatch - you either have to change the code (just remove the properties) or add the hyphens to the A-Error/B-Error in JSON.

Comment: @CaiusJard sure, but then that _would mean they differ_ hence....

Comment: I suppose the other good thing about JsonPropping everything, is that you can refactor at will..

Answer (score 3):

This is supposed to be the *name of the property in the json*

```
[JsonProperty("B-Error")]
```

`"B-Error"` is not the name of the property in your json; your json property is called `"BError"` - you seem to have a similar typo on A-Status

Do this, and everything will work:

```
[JsonProperty("BError")]
```

JsonProperty allows you to have C# properties that are called one thing, that connect to a json property called another thing. It means you can maintain c# naming conventions for your c# properties (you should rename your c# property `code` to `Code`) even though the json isn't named like c# would be

To get a full set of working classes together with hints about how to deserialize, just paste your json into https://QuickType.io

Comment: I know by changing the json property from "BError" to "B-Error" will work but I should not change it

Comment: you're supposed to change JsonProperty to match the json, not change the json to match the JsonProperty!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a constructor if you want it the way you want

```
public partial class Demo
{
    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("B-Error")]
    public BError BError { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("A-Status")]
    public bool AStatus { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Demo(DateTimeOffset Date,string Name, BError BError, bool AStatus)
    {
        this.Date=Date;
        this.Name=Name;
        this.BError=BError;
        this.AStatus=AStatus;
    }
}
public partial class BError
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

this json was tested and code is working properly

```
{
   "Date":"2021-11-16",
   "Name":"Raj",
   "BError":{
      "code":"errorcode",
      "details":"message"
   },
   "AStatus":true
}
```

Comment: No I want JsonProperties with hypen (B-Error , A-Status)

Comment: You have to change your json  then

Comment: without changing either of one we can't get the result?

Comment: What sense it makes?  You  have to make json with hypen or not  there is no another way. Attributes don' t do anything. You can' t make c# properties with hypen

Comment: If you absolutely have do you could try some hack by for instance replacing "AError" with "A-Error" in the input string - I cannot see the point here thou.
`responseJson = responseJson.Replace("AError", "A-Error");`